# Where can I see my EndPoint log in Hbase?

Tags: hbase, endpoint

I write an `EndPoint` server as follow:

```
public class HelloWorldEndPoint extends ServerHelloworld.HelloWorld implements Coprocessor, CoprocessorService {

    private RegionCoprocessorEnvironment env;

    @Override
    public void sendHello(RpcController controller, HelloRequest request,
                          RpcCallback<HelloResponse> done) {
        System.out.println("request HelloRequest:" + request.getAskWord());
        HelloResponse resp = HelloResponse.newBuilder().setRetWord(ByteString.copyFromUtf8("hello world!!!")).build();

        done.run(resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void question(RpcController controller, AskRequest request,
                         RpcCallback<AnsResponse> done) {
        System.out.println("request question:" + request.getAsk());
        AnsResponse resp = AnsResponse.newBuilder().setAns(ByteString.copyFromUtf8("helloworld," + request.getAsk().toStringUtf8())).build();
        done.run(resp);
    }

    @Override
    public Service getService() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(CoprocessorEnvironment env) throws IOException {
        if (env instanceof RegionCoprocessorEnvironment) {
            this.env = (RegionCoprocessorEnvironment) env;
        } else {
            throw new CoprocessorException("Must be loaded on a table region!");
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is I can not see my log, such as:

```
System.out.println("request question:" + request.getAsk());
```

I do not know where can I see this

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint is running on RegionServer. Usually, regionserver logs are present under `/var/log/hbase` directory. You should find the log for Endpoint in that directory in sysout logfile. 
Also, you will need to `locate the region server`(if you are running on a distributed cluster)  that is receiving endpoint-client request.

Comment: sorry, I reply later, but I don't find `/var/log/hbase` directory in my machine

Comment: @roger: Are you running a distributed cluster or standalone cluster on your machine? I gave you info for a distributed cluster.